# SQl get counts from multiple CTEs into one table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, common-table-expression

I have multiple CTEs which all come from the same table, "table1". And all they return is a count of the rows. The differences between each CTE is the contents of the where statements as I want to compare the counts when I make these small changes. The code looks like:

```
WITH cte1 AS(
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table1
WHERE....
), cte2 AS(
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table1
WHERE....
), cte3 AS(
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table 1
WHERE....
)
```

I want to get an output where I get all the counts from each CTE and just have them in one table like:

```
cte1      cte2      cte3
1,564     3,567     2,861
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as all of your CTEs return only 1 row you can just do the cartesian product of all of them (all in the from clause with no joins). I believe you will need to give a column alias to your count(*) expression to include them in your CTE as well.

```
WITH cte1 AS(
 SELECT COUNT(*) cnt 
 FROM table1
 WHERE....
), cte2 AS(
 SELECT COUNT(*) cnt
 FROM table1
 WHERE....
), cte3 AS(
 SELECT COUNT(*) cnt
 FROM table 1
 WHERE....
)
SELECT cte1.cnt AS cte1, cte2.cnt AS cte2, cte3.cnt AS cte3
FROM cte1, cte2, cte3
```

Also if you don't have any joins in your CTE you can potentially run the counts simultaneously by using sum case expressions which may increase performance.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN /* where clause 1 */ THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) cte1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN /* where clause 2 */ THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) cte2,  
       SUM(CASE WHEN /* where clause 3 */ THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) cte3
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE....) as cte1,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE....) as cte2,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE....) as cte3
```